# Spring CassandraTemplate throwing NoHostAvailableException when closing the app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cassandra

I have a spring application which consumes from a Kafka topic and runs some real time queries on Cassandra during processing. The application starts fine, runs fine, but when I close the application, the current batch (Kafka batch) that was being processed throws

> org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraConnectionFailureException:
>   All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried); nested
>   exception is
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All
>   host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)

From the [stack-trace](https://pastebin.com/D67NhwBY), the streaming query that I run on Cassandra fails at

> org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate$ResultSetIteratorAdapter.hasNext(CassandraTemplate.java:1218)

throwing the above exception

EDIT

So its a spring-boot application with actuator. I use the /shutdown endpoint of actuator to shutdown app. I am using Spring Cassandra repositories to interact with my DB. I do not explicitly close any connections.

The error comes during a streaming read. When I hit the /shutdown endpoint, 9 times out of 10 this read is being performed and it fails. JPA and mongo are able to shutdown gracefully.

```
int[] fareTrend = fareInfoRepository.findByOriginAndDestinationAndEventTimeAfter(originCode, destinationCode,
                                                                                         Instant.now().minusSeconds(FARE_TREND_THRESHOLD_SECONDS))
                                            .filter(fareInfo -> departureRange.contains(fareInfo.getDepartureDate()))
                                            .filter(fareInfo -> "e".equals(fareInfo.getFareDetails().getCabinClass()))
                                            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(FareInfo::getEventTime))
                                            .mapToInt(FareInfo::getTotalFare).toArray();
```

The repository :

```
@Repository
public interface FareInfoRepository extends CassandraRepository<FareInfo> {

    Stream<FareInfo> findByAdvancePurchaseDays(short advancepurchasedays);

    Stream<FareInfo> findByOriginAndDestinationAndEventTimeAfter(String origin, String destination, Instant eventTimeLimit);
}
```

The main class :

```
@ComponentScan("com.ixigo.analytics")
@EntityScan("com.ixigo.analytics.common.jpa.models")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.ixigo.analytics.common.jpa.repos")
@EnableCassandraRepositories("com.ixigo.analytics.common.cassandra.repos")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class)
public class DispatcherMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DispatcherMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Cassandra [configuration](https://pastebin.com/uUP6sBEk).

Comment: can you provide code snippets with this one? How you are actually closing the connection? Did you flush before stopping?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but from my analysis the query, "findByOriginAndDestinationAndEventTimeAfter()", was taking a lot of time and would cause the Kafka consumer to effectively get stuck and when I tried to shutdown it would cause that error. 
I reworked my logic to make the processing *much* faster and now I'm not getting the error.